# Why are Byte.compare() and Integer.compare() implemented differently?

Tags: java, compareto

I am studying the source of the OpenJDK.

My attention was attracted by the methods `Byte.compare()` and `Integer.compare()`:

```
public static int Byte.compare(byte x, byte y) {
    return x-y;
}

public static int Integer.compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Why do the methods `Byte.compare()` and `Integer.compare()` have different implementations?

Comment: @Discipol your statement is correct, but that's not the reason in that case! ;)

Comment: Hey, that Integer comparision never returns positive numbers, is that just a typo in + - 1 ?

Comment: there seems to be an error in the snippet you pasted: it should be `return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);`

Comment: Above implementation of int compare() doesn't return +ve value ever.  Is it correct?

Comment: You are right. I modified question. Sorry, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The implementation of `Integer.compare` does not use subtraction, as this could cause an overflow in case you're comparing an integer that is close to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` with another that is close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

This overflow cannot happen in case of `Byte.compare`, as there the byte values are implicitely converted to integers before `x-y` is calculated.

(see also: [Java Language Specification - 5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2))

Answer (score 8):

The Byte method can be implemented this way, becasue the result of the subtraction is representable in `int`. This is not so in the other case. For example:

```
0 - 0x80000000 == 0x80000000
```

and this is negative, hence the comparision would wrongly indicate that 0 is smaller than -2^31